# Text emphasis over lines, using Manim

Tags: python, math, manim

Is there a way that the lines can be animated, and that the text converse the emphasis?

As you can see in the picture of the video (link added), the lines move around and when colide the text, the lines get thinner.

I have looked in the MANIM documentation, but have no idea how do this.

https://youtu.be/3d6DsjIBzJ4?t=101

Manim Version = https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text box probabily have a color of black and sub 1 opacity, and placed on top of the graph

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30302226)